# jquery get whole option selected in html

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Is there possibility to get all html option from selected dropdown.
While i have

```
<select class="myselect">
  <option data-one="11" data-two="11" data-three="111" value="1">Some text here</option>
  <option data-one="22" data-two="22" data-three="222" value="2">Some text here2</option>
</select>
```

I would like to get whole option which is:

```
<option data-one="22" data-two="22" data-three="222" value="2">Some text here2</option>
```

As far i as tried i can get all options in html by:

```
$('.myselect').html()
```

Or just one data by :

```
$('.myselect').find(':selected').data('one')
```

Or just one value

```
$('.myselect').find(':selected').val()
```

So is there simple way to get selected whole html option from < option >... to < /option>

Answer (score 2):

Like this - it is not clear if you want the tag or the data attributes so here are either

```js
$(".myselect").on("change",function() {
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex]); // complete tag
  console.log(this.options[this.selectedIndex].dataset); // array of data attribute values
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect">
  <option value="">Please select</option>
  <option data-one="11" data-two="11" data-three="111" value="1">Some text here</option>
  <option data-one="22" data-two="22" data-three="222" value="2">Some text here2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks you very much +1 form me. Works great

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't quite clear precisely what result you wanted, so here are a couple of ideas to get things you may be interested in:

1) To get the names and values of all the data-attributes you can just call `.data()` without any arguments and it will return all the data-attributes and their values in an object. There's also an example [in the documentation](https://api.jquery.com/data/).

2) To get the whole HTML of the selected item you can use `outerHTML` on the DOM element found by jQuery.

Demo of each below:

```js
//to get the data-attributes
var selectedData = $('.myselect').find(':selected').data();
console.log(selectedData);

//to get the HTML of the selected item:
var selected = $('.myselect').find(':selected')[0].outerHTML;
console.log(selected);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="myselect">
  <option data-one="11" data-two="11" data-three="111" value="1">Some text here</option>
  <option data-one="22" data-two="22" data-three="222" value="2">Some text here2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: I think he [wants the tag](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61591466/295783)?

Comment: @mplungjan literally just editing it as you wrote that :-)

Comment: i wasn't editing. As i wrote i wanted that as an output

<option data-one="22" data-two="22" data-three="222" value="2">Some text here2</option>

Comment: $('.myselect').find(':selected')[0].outerHTML; Works as well. Thank you too

Comment: @Baltrek No problem. P.S. I meant I was editing my answer, not you :-)